# How do I group d3 elements generated from external data?

Tags: d3.js, grouping

I have lines and labels that are both being generated from an external data source. What I want is for each iteration of these to be put in a group, so the code looks something like this:

```
<g>
  <text>Text</text>
  <line></line>
</g>
<g>
  <text>Text</text>
  <line></line>
</g>
<g>
  <text>Text</text>
  <line></line>
</g>

...
...
...
```

This is my code now which groups all of the elements in one group element:

```
  var group = svg.append("g");

  var labels = group.selectAll('text')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
    .append('text')
      .attr("class", "text")
      .attr('x',function (d) { return xScale(d['Untitled']) + 50})
      .attr('y',function (d) { return yScale(d['Untitled2']) - 31.2})
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .style("text-decoration", "underline")
      .style("cursor", "move")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name });

  var lines = group.selectAll('line')
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('line')
      .attr('class', 'line')
      .style("stroke", "#000")
      .style("stroke-width", .7)
      .attr('x1',function (d) { return xScale(d['Untitled'])})
      .attr('y1',function (d) { return yScale(d['Untitled2'])})
      .attr('x2',function (d) { return xScale(d['Untitled']) + 50})
      .attr('y2',function (d) { return yScale(d['Untitled2']) - 30});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
  const data = [
    { id: 1, value: 10, label: 'aaa' },
    { id: 2, value: 20, label: 'bbb' },
    { id: 3, value: 30, label: 'ccc' }
  ];

  const svg = d3.select('body').append('svg')
    .attr('width', 500)
    .attr('height', 500);

  const g = svg.selectAll('g').data(data, (d) => {
    return d.id;
  });

  const groupEnter = g.enter().append('g');

  groupEnter
    .append('text')
    .text((d) => {
      return d.label;
    })

  groupEnter
    .append('line', (d) => {
      return d.value;
    })
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5vpchf30/)

Basically, the idea is to take the return selection of `g.enter().append('g');` and call append two times, the first one to append the text and the second to append the line.

I hope it helps.